# how to define different layouts for each page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, page

I want to know if is possible to create different layouts for each page.
In my `Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` I have the copy of the `Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` and I want to add this block:

```
<referenceContainer name="head.components">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.changer" template="Magento_Theme::head-changer.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

But I want this to be applied only in my our-services.phtml page.
Can someone tell me if this is possible, and if it is how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page you are referring to is a CMS Page this layout adjustment (quoted by you) can be added to "Layout Update" field while editing the CMS Page from Admin panel.

If the page has it's own controller, the block should be added to layout file with `module_controller_action.xml` name corresponding to action that is rendering the page.

Comment: how can I create an own controller to a specific page?

Comment: You can create a page using a controller, not vise-a-verse. CMS Pages are handled by ```Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index``` controller and cms_index_index.xml layout, so the only option here is adding layout update from admin panel (or installing it to db).